# Update android app from own server [Android]

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to update my app without google play. I put apk file on public server and I downloaded it successfully.
After that I open this apk and I try to install but it finished with names conflict. Is there any option to replace apk itself? Thanks in advance!

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

            var uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Application.Context, "com.test.app.provider", file);
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);

            Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate app that does nothing but checking the version of your app against your server and update the app if needed. The installer-app tells your app to stop, then it installs the new version and starts it. The user does get a popup during install, you can't fully automatically install an app from another app unless your app is signed with the signing key of the manufacturer of the device, or you have rooted the device.

I can post some code later, I'm not at my own computer right now.

Comment: Thanks! But I dont want to create another app-manager, maybe is there any option to replace main app by itself?

Comment: You can't save it when it's still running.